# What's the best way to make a bitwise function work for any type of integer input c++?

Tags: c++, performance, void-pointers

So I need to read flags in bits and set flags in bits. These bits are in various sizes of integer: int16, int32, int64, etc.

I would like to have a function that does something like this:

```
static integertype function(integertype data, char startbit, char endbit);
```

I don't want to code what will be the same code to isolate bits from for different sizes of integers in separate but identical functions (for the multitude of bit functions I want to write).

I thought about using a void pointer for the data so everything could run through one function. Is this a bad design? What about as far as efficiency goes? I have no concept of bad/good design due to my inexperience.

```
static int function(void *data, char startbit, char endbit)
```

These flags have to be looked at very often as this is for a data acquisition system. Would a void pointer implementation be reasonably efficient?

I know premature optimization is bad, but I would like to know what things are generally less or more efficient than others so I can make good decisions.

Thanks in advance for taking me to school.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, if you need generic functionality you use templates:

```
template <typename T>
T function(T data, char startbit, char endbit);
```

But keep in mind we have [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/).

Comment: Cool guys. I didn't know you could do templated functions in C++, and definitely didn't know about std::bitset.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This website helped me understand std::bitset and other options. http://www.drdobbs.com/184401382;jsessionid=GTHEKBIV3CLBVQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN

Comment: @Johnny: Glad to help. Perhaps you might pick up a good C++ book to help solidify and expand your knowledge? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 5):

Why not make it a templated function?

```
template<typename T>
static T foobar(T data, char startbit, char endbit);
```